# What is the use of "object sender" and "EventArgs e" parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, sender, eventargs

In case of `Page_Load`, `Init` and other page events, what is the use of these `(object sender, EventArgs e)` parameters?

Examples would be more helpful.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`EventArgs e` is a parameter called e that contains the event data, see the EventArgs MSDN page for more information.

`Object Sender` is a parameter called Sender that contains a reference to the control/object that raised the event.

Event Arg Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx

Example:

```
protected void btn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e){
   Button btn = sender as Button;
   btn.Text = "clicked!";
}
```

**Edit:**
When Button is clicked, the btn_Click event handler will be fired. The "object sender" portion will be a reference to the button which was clicked

Comment: But how is the sender related to the button? Where is the relationship constructed between `sender` and `btn`?

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli, The relationship between 'sender' and 'Button' in the inheritance hierarchy, is that they are both 'object' types.  'sender' is simply a wrapper for an 'object' type. When unboxed at run-time, the underlying instance of the wrapped object is projected to the capturing class. In this case 'Button'.   If the expected class does not match the unboxed object, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 41):

Those two parameters (or variants of) are sent, by convention, with all events.

- `sender`: The object which has raised the event
- `e` an instance of `EventArgs` including, in many cases, an object which inherits from `EventArgs`. Contains additional information about the event, and sometimes provides ability for code handling the event to alter the event somehow.

In the case of the events you mentioned, neither parameter is particularly useful. The is only ever one page raising the events, and the `EventArgs` are `Empty` as there is no further information about the event.

Looking at the 2 parameters separately, here are some examples where they *are* useful.

### `sender`

Say you have multiple buttons on a form. These buttons could contain a `Tag` describing what clicking them should do. You could handle all the `Click` events with the same handler, and depending on the `sender` do something different

```
private void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    if(btn.Tag == "Hello")
      MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    else if(btn.Tag == "Goodbye")
       Application.Exit();
    // etc.
}
```

Disclaimer : That's a contrived example; don't do that!

### `e`

Some events are cancelable. They send `CancelEventArgs` instead of `EventArgs`. This object adds a simple boolean property `Cancel` on the event args. Code handling this event can cancel the event:

```
private void HandleCancellableEvent(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(/* some condition*/)
    {
       // Cancel this event
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for Cancellable Events.  What are some real-world examples in the Windows applications world? Thanks.

Comment: @DaveKelly Thanks.