# Focus selected controls by pressing Enter Key

Tags: c#, winforms

In C# windows application to navigate all control of a Form (using Enter Key) I am using the below code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
}
```

N.B.: Form Property `KeyPreview = True;`

The above code works fine but when I am going to navigate between two `dateTimePicker` (`dateTimePicker1`, `dateTimePicker2`) pressing Enter Key. 
When Form open Focus on `dateTimePicker1` and press Enter Key then Focus `dateTimePicker2` and press Enter Key Focus `dateTimePicker1`.

The below code works fine without the above code. What is the best way to navigate the two `dateTimePicker` using the above code or any other way?

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
        dateTimePicker2.Focus();
    }
}

private void dateTimePicker2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
        dateTimePicker1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Anybody please help me.

Comment: It's enough to use the first solution to navigate between all controls. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't see a question either.  It is a bad habit to get into, the Enter key just plays a very different role in a GUI.  It is used to operate the default button of a window, the one selected by the Form.AcceptButton property.  And to add lines to a RichTextBox and a multi-line TextBox.  Very occasionally to solve a UX problem, the address box of a browser for example.  Users are content to use the Tab key and the cursor keys to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe your two `DateTimePickers` to the same event handler instead of using two events, and use the [`sender`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479143/what-is-the-use-of-object-sender-and-eventargs-e-parameters) object:

```
private void dateTimePicker_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var dtp = sender as DateTimePicker;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (dtp?.Name[dtp.Name.Length - 1] == '1')
            dateTimePicker2.Focus();
        else dateTimePicker1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Just don't forget to change the value of the `KeyDown` event in the properties window of the both `DateTimePickrs` to point to this event.